# Can't log into Joomla frontend

Tags: joomla, web, account

So we just started a website (poweronfilms.com). We only have 2 accounts so far. Josh (the superuser) and me. I am marked as an administrator. For some reason, every time I try to log into the frontend, it just reloads the page. If I put in false credentials, It tells me I have the wrong username/password. But If they're correct, it doesn't do anything. I can still log into the backend just fine though, and it tells me I'm logged in to the site, but I can't access it. Our superuser can still log on.

Comment: Don't know who downvoted your question and why (just upvoted to nullify the downvote effect). I don't think it should be downvoted. It is a valid Joomla question concerning a problem affecting many Joomla administrators out there.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable reason that it gives error for wrong credential but for valid credential it's not allowing you to login is might be because you have set wrong cookie domain in configuration.php

```
public $cookie_domain = '';
```

Recheck that setting, if it points to correct one or try with blank.

Answer (score 0):

There's a myriad of reasons of why you are redirected back to the login page without any error, it might be:

- Unwritable `tmp` and/or `logs` folder
- Non-empty cookie domain
- Forced caching in the `.htaccess` file (see [here](http://www.itoctopus.com/yet-another-login-loop-in-joomlas-backend) )
- Invalid session handler

The above list is not exhaustive.

Comment: Our superuser can still log on.

Comment: It turned out that "administrator" had offline access turned off.

Comment: Indeed it is not exhaustive. My recent encounter with this issue was resolved by clearing the cache for that site.